# how to print a pattern from a line in a column in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file A.txt (sep=","):

```
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export = 07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
,taq,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
,taq,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

And I want to add a pattern from line 3 in the first column of my file after line 13, like that :

```
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export = 07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC,taq,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC,taq,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

The trick is to set " = " as separator for B.txt in order to print the data of A.txt in the $1 of B.txt. I've try stuff like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=" = "} NR==3{stuff} } 1' A.txt > B.txt
```

But i didn't figure it out. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F' = ' 'NR==3{a=$2} {if(NR<14)print; else print a $0}' A.txt
```

Using your sample input:

```
$ awk -F' = ' 'NR==3{a=$2} {if(NR<14)print; else print a $0}' A.txt
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export = 07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC,taq,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC,taq,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
```

#### Multiline format

For those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
awk -F' = ' '
    NR==3{
        a=$2
    }

    {
        if(NR<14)
            print
        else
            print a $0
    }
    ' A.txt
```

#### How it works

- -`F' = '`

  This sets the field separator to `=`.
- `NR==3{a=$2}`

  For line number three, this saves the second field in variable `a`.
- `if(NR<14)print; else print a $0`

  For line number less than 14, this prints the line unchanged.  For the remaining lines, this prints the line with variable `a` in front of it.

#### Update: Adding time from lines 14 to all but the last four lines

```
awk -F' = ' 'NR==3{t=$2} NR<14{print;next} NR>17{print t d} {d=c;c=b;b=a;a=$0} END{print d ORS c ORS b ORS a}' A.txt
```

Example input file:

```
$ cat A.txt
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export = 07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
,taq,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
,taq,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
end1
end2
end3
end4
```

Corresponding output:

```
$ awk -F' = ' 'NR==3{t=$2} NR<14{print;next} NR>17{print t d} {d=c;c=b;b=a;a=$0} END{print d ORS c ORS b ORS a}' A.txt
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export = 07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC,taq,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC,taq,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
end1
end2
end3
end4
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail response, it's awesome ! But in the end of my file I have 4 lines ( 2 in my example ) where I should not print the data : Can I do something with `tail -n+4` ?

Comment: @nstatam OK.  I'm not sure I know what you're asking but, if you want to cut off (remove) the last 4 lines of output, use `head -n-4`

Comment: @nstatam Do you want to remove the last 4 lines or leave them unchanged?  Is there some distinctive feature of those lines?  It looks like that the lines that you want to change have `taq` in them.   Do the last 4 lines lack `taq`?

Comment: I don't want to cut off,  just `print $0` on those lines

Comment: @nstatam OK.  See the new code at the end of the answer and tell me if it does what you want.  (It is tuned for 4 unchanged lines at the end since that is your real case.)

Comment: Thanks for helping me. So the 4 last lines are in fact correctly print without changes, but 4 lines are added whith the date print after the line 13

Comment: @nstatam Sorry about that!  It's getting late here.  Answer updated to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks it's perfect. Again, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

A "line agnostic" version

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '$0~/UTC/{split($0,ar,"= ")}$2=="taq"{$1=ar[2]}1' file

kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export = 07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC,taq,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC,taq,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

Set `FS` and `OFS` to `,` but split out the date into the array `ar` on the line where you find `UTC` and then just insert in as `$1` wherever `$2=="taq"`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the only line with an UTC pattern and $2  can have several pattern